# C : File redirection is not working

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

I am trying to do a simple `scanf` and `printf` in the C program below:

1. getting the user input
2. checking if the user input is correct, if so, printing it out, else displaying a error message

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
    int latitude;
    int scanfout;
    int started = 1;

    puts("enter the value:");

    while (started == 1) {
        scanfout = scanf("%d", &latitude);
        if (scanfout == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", latitude);
            printf("ok return code:%d\n", scanfout);
            puts("\n");
        } else {
            puts("value not a valid one");
            printf("not ok return code:%d\n", scanfout);        
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tried compiling and running it at a command terminal, program works.
 command line output:

```
enter the value:
1
1
ok returncode:1

0
0
ok returncode:1

122.22
122
ok returncode:1

sad
value not a valid one
not ok returncode:0
```

As you can see, the program simply scans the user input and prints it out, it works fine in command line, but when it try to redirect the input to a text file say:

```
test < in.txt
```

the program doesn't work and the print statements in the else part goes on printing in an infinite loop. The text file `in.txt` contains a single value `12`, instead of printing `12`, the program simply goes into a infinite loop and prints:

```
value not a valid one
not ok returncode:0
value not a valid one
not ok returncode:0
value not a valid one
not ok returncode:0
value not a valid one
not ok returncode:0
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is the code correct, why it works from command line and why file redirection doesn't work? help would be appreciated...

Comment: Your program does not handle incorrect (non-integer) input correctly. Nothing much to do with the redirection. `scanf` does not consume the non-matching input. And `fflush(stdin)` does not do that either (it's Undefined Behaviour on some platforms and on Linux it only flushes any buffered data not the unread data).

Comment: Try using `fgets` and then `sscanf` or `strtol` instead.

Comment: kaylum,Thanks for your response,you were saying that the program doesnt handle incorrect data correctly,but when running the exe and if i give a dummy value: sadsdfs or some incorrect data,it does print the code inside the else part,the problem is only occuring when i try to redirect the input to a file instead of a user input,it would be really  helpful if you can correct the code and show me the part which is wrong..

Comment: what exactly is in the file `in.txt` ? Preferable you should show a hexdump of that file.

Comment: The problem is `fflush(stdin)`. It's in general Undefined Behaviour and not predictable at best. It may work on a particular system but it will not always work (not portable at best) - it certainly does not work on my Linux system and invalid input from the terminal will result in the infinete loop that you see. Bottom line - avoid doing `fflush(stdin)`. See for example: [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not test for end of file: when the input file has been scanned, the program goes into an infinite loop because `scanf` return `-1`, the program complains and retries.

Incidentally, if there is data in the input file that cannot be converted to an `int`, the program will loop forever trying to reparse the same input in vain.

Note that `fflush(stdin);` is not specified in the C Standard, it may or may not do what you expect it to, especially from a file.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
    int latitude, scanfout, c;

    puts("enter the value:");

    for (;;) {
        scanfout = scanf("%d", &latitude);
        if (scanfout == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", latitude);
            printf("ok return code:%d\n", scanfout);
            puts("\n");
        } else
        if (scanfout < 0) {
            break;   // End of file 
        } else {
            puts("value not a valid one");
            printf("not ok return code:%d\n", scanfout);        
        }
        /* read and ignore the rest of the line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi,can you please correct the code and show me the correct one,it would be helpful....